# assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE) when using python multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am currently trying to use python multiprocessing. The library I use is `multiprocess` (NOT `multiprocessing`).

I have the following code, which creates a number of computing jobs, and runs it through a map operation:

```
pool = multiprocess.Pool(4)
all_responses = pool.map_async(wrapper_singlerun, range(10000))
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

However, whenever I run this snippet of code, I get the following error:

```
    pool.join()
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 509, in join
    assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE)
AssertionError
```

Do you have any idea why this error happens? I used `pool.map_async` before, but figured that I need to have a `pool rendez-vous` command. Otherwise, my PC created something like a forkbomb, which created too many threads (at least, that's what I think it does...)

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Do you have that code inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, or just at the top level of your module?

Comment: This piece of code is encoded within a class, which is instantiated within a few layers of functions. The initial function is indeed within `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: The [`multiprocess` homepage](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) links to [docs that don't exist](http://multiprocess.readthedocs.io/). which makes it pretty hard to debug anything that isn't the same as `multiprocessing`. But it seems like the only differences are that (a) `multiprocess` pre-monkeypatches `dill` in place of `pickle` and (b) may be a few versions behind. So… can you repro the same problem with `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Apparently I have the same problem with `multiprocessing` (when I replace the `pool = multiprocess.Pool(4)` with `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)`

Comment: @abarnert, more specifically, the `multiprocessing` module gives me a pickling error, that's why I switched to the other library (as it uses dill)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `join` before `close`.

[`multiprocess`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) appears to be [missing its documentation](http://multiprocess.readthedocs.io/), but, as far as I can tell, it's basically a fork of the stdlib `multiprocessing` that pre-monkeypatches `dill` in for `pickle`, so the `multiprocessing` docs should be relevant here. (Also, in a comment, you said that you can repro the problem with `multiprocessing`.)

So, [`Pool.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) says:

> Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call `close()` or `terminate()` before using `join()`.

The `close` method is how you shut down the send side of the queue so new tasks can't be added. The `join` method is how you wait for everything on the queue to be processed. Waiting for the queue to drain before closing it wouldn't work.

But you're calling `close` after `join`, instead of before. And [the first thing `join` does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L543) is `assert` that you've already called `close` or `terminate`, which you haven't, hence the assertion failure.

So, you probably just want to switch the order of those two calls.

Or, alternatively, maybe you were confused about what `join` is for, and thought you needed to call it before you could use `all_responses.get()` or `.wait()`. If so—you don't need to do that; the `get` will block until the results are available, after which you don't need a `join`. This is actually more common, especially with `map` and friends (although the examples in the docs do it via a `with Pool(…) as pool:` instead of manually calling anything on the pool).

Comment: @abamert, this is very helpful. If this chunk of code is in a loop, since the pool is closed after every loop, can I 'reopen' the pool at the beginning of the next loop or do I have to do a new `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)` in every loop?